# Re-size the Kendo RangeSlider while Minimize the window of browser

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to resize the kendo range slider when minimize the window of browser

When browser window is maximize kendo range slider show be like

[image]

When browser window is minimize kendo range slider show be like

[image]

So, just I want to do that when browser window minimize then kendo range slider should be responsive and hence after minimize the browser window it kendo range slider should be full size.

Here is my code

```
 var id;
 $(window).resize(function () {
 clearTimeout(id);
 id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 5);
 });

 function doneResizing() {
 var rangeSlider = $("#slider-range").getKendoRangeSlider();
 rangeSlider.wrapper.css("width", "100%");
 rangeSlider.resize();
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean when user resize window then slider should be at it's last position or it should be the full size always?

Comment: See, did you get any console error?

Comment: No, there is nothing type of error is coming.

Comment: Here very important things is at where you put this code and does it affect or not at all, so just put alert after this `$(window).resize(function () {` and check does your function called when you resize the window.

Comment: Yah this one already done and getting alert also.

Comment: *Yah this one already done* Then add in the question, that i have tried this many thing. how we know the issue, It's kind of *is not working* which is off topic

Comment: Sorry for that. So now you know that alert is coming so is there any idea to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I binded the Slider in the dataBound Event of a TreeView. This way I initialised this Slider twice, and wasn't able to resize my Slider.

To prevent this double initialization I checked for null on getKendoRangeSlider() on that element if null then make Slider:

```
var rangeSlider = $("#slider-range").getKendoRangeSlider();

if(rangeSlider == null){
    $("#slider-range").kendoRangeSlider({
        min: 10,
        max: 50,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 10
    });
}
$(window).on('resize', function () {
  var sliders = $("[data-role='slider']");
  sliders.each(function (index, ele) {
    var slider = $(ele).data("kendoSlider");
    slider.wrapper.css("width", "100%");
    slider.resize();
  });
});
```

This was also the case for KendoSlider